# how do you typically tie the address pins and WP pin of I2C device? Do these lines need a pull-up/down resistor or just tied directly

Tags: i2c, device

how do you typically tie the address pins and WP pin of I2C device?  Do these lines need a pull-up/down resistor or just tied directly.

Comment: Reading the datasheet would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 2):

> Do these lines need a pull-up/down resistor or just tied directly.

***Completely dependent on the specific IC you are using, and would be listed in the data sheet.*** Either outright, or in the recommended/typical application schematic.

That said, I've never personally seen one that couldn't be directly tied to VCC or Gnd. Unless it is one of the fancier ones that can be tied to voltage dividers, or the other address pins, or left floating.

---

### Your specific part, the FM24V02 has both an explicit explanation, and a typical application schematic. Direct Connections shown.

> A2-A0, Input, Device Select Address 2-0.
>   These pins are used to select one of up to 8 devices of the same type on the same I2C bus. To select the device, the address value on the three pins must match the corresponding bits contained in the slave address. **The address pins are pulled down internally.**
>
> WP, Input, Write Protect.
>   **When tied to VDD**, addresses in the entire memory map will be write-protected. **When WP is connected to ground**, all addresses are write enabled. **This pin is pulled down internally.**

[image]

Comment: Ok, nothing is mentioned in datasheet. So i can tie directly to VDD or VSS as per my requirement

Comment: @engineer what part, what data sheet

Comment: FM24V02 F-RAM part

Comment: page 3 of the datasheet says " When tied to VDD, addresses in the entire memory map will be write-protected. When
WP is connected to ground, all addresses are write enabled. This pin is pulled down internally." I think that's pretty clear.

Comment: My question for slave address pins A0, A1, A2. Even these pins are pulled down internally, if i want to pull down externally, should i tie directly to VSS or through resistor?

Comment: @engineer: Depends on how certain you are you won't want to change the configuration during development.  It's really hard to change the strapping on a pin tied directly to ground if that trace is underneath the chip.  A zero-ohm resistor can be removed and easily jumpered to the opposite rail.  To save on part cost, you can run the trace thru a pad then to ground (or VCC) in a way that makes it easy to cut the trace and then jumper to that pad.

Comment: @engineer: See [this question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/148935/1743) for how to do that.

Comment: @engineer: if the pins are pulled down internally, there is no need to pull them down externally.  If you want one or more of the address pins pulled High, those pins can be connected directly to Vdd.